# Flutter's CupertinoDatePicker localization issues

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-localizations

Would anyone know why the `CupertinoDatePicker` would display the days in English but the months in French ? My iPhone 6 is running iOS 12 is in French. I also reproduce this issue on my iPhone X running iOS 16 and also in French.

I am using `PlatformApp` from the `platform_widgets` package and I made sure to provide all the relevant localizations delegate:

```
localizationsDelegates: const [
  AppLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
],
supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
```

[image: picture of the app]

How can I fix that ? Thanks !